# Are Playstation Plus subscriptions region locked?

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

I currently live in the UK, however Playstation Plus is cheaper for the American version (£27) than the UK version (£41) on CDkeys. I am unsure if this will work or not - I do not care about the games on PS Plus, I simply want to play online and save a bit of money.

Will this work?

Answer (score -1):

Yes You can all you will have to change the region to what place you want on your ps account.

Comment: Can you put the relevant information of the video into your answer? Answers should be self-contained and that way it will remain useful even when the video disappears.